# Which advertise module to use with phonegap

Tags: cordova

hey guys please provide me with which advertising modules can be used with phonegap such as admob, google adsense etc......with tutorial for how to integrate those modules

I am relatively newbie to phonegap...

Comment: You know you're supposed to accept an answer when one of them answers your question ? If none of them does, then maybe you should provide more information about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I never did it but, here's what I found using google

http://iphone.keyvisuals.com/iphonedev/implementing-admob-ads-in-a-phonegap-project-for-ios-no-plugins-required/

http://forum.cibermonde.com/index.php?showtopic=24112

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/AdPlugin

Did you try these ?